# How to bookmark ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I am working on an ajax site with jquery. I am able to load pages and change the url with history.pushState(). I can navigate to http://example.com/some-url and I can go back to http://example.com/ but I cannot reload http://example.com/some-url. Reloading it will give me a 404. This is my goal http://html5.gingerhost.com/

Thanks

Comment: you need to have actual URLs that work if you want what you describe, otherwise use hash navigation

Comment: alternative to hash navigation is server side url rewrite - need to know what http server you're running to help with that